Merge a split chunk back into the entrypoint
I have a module with a good handful of chunks A, B, C, and D, all of which rely on a shared utilities file which Rollup separately chunks.
Because this utilities file is only a couple of Kb, and because every single child chunk requires it, I want to merge this utilities file back into the main entrypoint. It does absolutely no good as a chunk on it's own.
However, I can't figure out how to do this. Rollup documents the manualChunks(id) option but it has absolutely no documentation on how you merge back into the entrypoint. Providing a generic name like index creates two index.<hash>.js files, one being the entrypoint and the second being my utilities file.
manualChunks(id) {
    if (id.includes('lib/utilities.js')) {
        return 'index';
    }
}

How can I force Rollup to hoist this module back up into the entrypoint?

How many entry points to you have? Can you post your current Vite config?

Just the single entry, there's absolutely nothing else in my config.

rollup-plugin-hoist-import-deps seems to be the closest for what I'm after, but requires quite a bit of modification.

Please share how you modified. Otherwise, this answer is not useful to others on SO.

It is useful, as it shows how you could go about doing so. I haven't done so myself.
